# How to temporarily disable a Wordpress site and enable another site with my Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I have a wordpress site at a Ubuntu 12.04 server with Apache installed as the web server. I would like to temporarily remove it from my website and enable another website (not wordpress, just plain HTML,PHP). How can I do that?

thanks

Comment: Move your website into another folder? Or have you thought of something special?

Comment: I am new to apache and i'm not too sure how does the folder structure or the config file work. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You can move everything to a new folder (e.g. named "old-wp" or so) and upload the new website to root directory.

Comment: then what if people visit http://mysite.com/old-wp ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960443/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-wordpress-site-and-enable-another-site-with-my-ubun/14961088#14961088

Comment: I tried the following:
$ mkdir /var/old-wp
$ mv /var/www/. /var/old-wp
I get the following message: Device or resource busy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24775/discussion-between-chris-yeung-and-fnkr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a dir called "old"
2. Move everything into "old"
3. Create a file called .htaccess inside the "old"-directory
4. Write the following into the .htaccess file:

   deny from all
5. Upload your new website inside the web-root directory

If you access the "old" directory from web you should get an forbidden message.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna try to do something better you can use **virtual hosts**

> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

In simple: you can run more sites at the same time on your server.

Comment: Already thought that but he want to replace his website and not create a second one :)

Comment: If this is the "ugly" goal, yes... change folder XD